# Save Model errors to flash Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to add hash with model errors to flash and after that redirect. This is the controller:

```
def update
    current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
    if current_user.errors.any?
        flash.keep[:errors] = current_user.errors.messages
    end
    byebug
    redirect_to edit_path
end
```

This is the view:

```
<div>
    <%=f.text_field :fname, placeholder: 'First Name', limit:50 %>
        <span><%=flash[:errors][:first_name]%></span>
</div>

<div>
    <%=f.text_field :lname, placeholder: 'Lirst Name', limit:50 %>
    <span><%=flash[:errors][:last_name]%></span>
</div>
```

With byebug, if I fill in inputs with invalid data and type in the console `flash[:errors]`, I see this output hash:

> {:first_name=>["First name must be minimum 1 character", "is invalid"], :last_name=>["is too short (minimum is 1 character)", "is invalid"]}

If I add in the view instead `<span><%=flash[:errors][:first_name]%></span>`, but :

```
<%=flash[:errors]%>
```

I see the same hash as a string in HTML:

```
<span>
   {"first_name"=>["First name must be minimum 1 character", "is invalid"],
   "last_name"=>["is too short (minimum is 1 character)", "is invalid"]}
</span>
```

How can I add and use hash with flash messages in Rails 5 ?

Comment: Is the hash key `errors` storing the `current_user.errors.messages`?, where's the problem, when showing the content in the view?, do you need to show them?

Comment: Hi, It is storing them, yes. If I type  in the console with byebug I see the hash with errors `flash[:errors]` or `current_user.errors.messages`, doesn't matter. They output same result (the hash with errors). The problem is that in the view, if I use `<%=flash[:errors][:last_name]` it is empty, but If I debug in the console, it is not empty. But, if I use `<%=flash[:errors]` it shows me entire hash with hall errors, but as a string.

Comment: In your last example of output, it's changint the hash keys from symbols to string, can you check you can access them as string instead? `<%=flash[:errors]['first_name']%>`?

Comment: Omg, thx a  lot. Add your answer to mark it as the right answer, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your hash is being changed from symbol keys:

```
{ :first_name => ..., :last_name  => ... }
```

to string keys:

```
{ "first_name" => ..., "last_name"  => ... }
```

then you could try accessing them as string, instead as now that you're doing it in the opposite way, like:

```
<span>
  <%= flash[:errors]['first_name'] %>
</span>
```